# partitions in windows and ubuntu, can't create more than 4 partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed dual boot windows 10 /ubuntu 14.04. As I went through the instructions I saw that by having an EFI bios I can only make 4 partitions max i.e 2 for windows ( primary c drive and a system generated one) and now I have 2 for ubuntu (swap and an ext4 ) is it alright if I make more partitions in windows ?

Comment: If Windows is installed in BIOS boot mode even on newer UEFI hardware, you have to use the 35 year old MBR(msdos) partitioning with 4 primary partition limit. If Windows installed in UEFI boot mode then it has to use the newer gpt partitioning which has a 'soft' limit of 128 partition essentially all primary. If MBR http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

To have more than 4 partitions on harddisk you should create one of those 4 extended. And then in extended create logical partitions.

You can check also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322695/more-than-4-partitions-with-ubuntu-windows-dual-boot), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71090/cannot-create-a-partition-after-the-4th/71124#71124), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316315/create-partition-from-free-space-cannot-create-more-than-4-partitions)

Comment: can i do it in windows now ?  Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: @AlenThomasAlex yes you can , by using Easy US partition master, free version will work for you, and if your partition scheme is MBR make sure to convert it to GPT

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh This is a dangerous advice, just converting a disk from MBR to GPT with installed operating systems will leave the computer unbootable.

Comment: @mook765 shit I didn't think about that, guess keeping a different SSD for OS's has made my judgement poor in these matters

Comment: Yeah, extended partition is the key.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Don't worry, I just had to comment to prevent an accident for the OP. Also the OP didn't give much information, just that his machine has UEFI, but what is on a disk is a different thing, we should have asked for the partition table type.

Comment: Whatever you do, *do not* use the stock Windows tools to create more than four partitions on an MBR disk, or to manipulate a disk that has extended/logical partitions. Microsoft's tools have had *serious* bugs in handling such disks for *years!* Instead, leave empty space on the disk and use Ubuntu's tools to create extended and logical partitions.